# How to pass additional parameters to WordPress wp_mail() function?

Tags: php, wordpress, email

I want to pass some additional data (i.e. the admin email address) every a mail is sent from WordPress.

If my web site was based on pure PHP, I would have to set parameter `additional_parameters` to `-f me@domain.com`. More info [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#additional_parameters).

However, my web site is based on WordPress and so I have to find another way to pass the additional parameter (i.e. the admin email address) to `wp_mail()` function.

How can I do that in Wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

[`wp_mail`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/) allows you to provide headers to the email. If you use the `From` header, you can specify who the email is from.

```
$headers = array('From: ' . get_option('admin_email'));

wp_mail('recipient@example.com', 'Email subject', 'Email Body', $headers);
```